# How to use traefik as a reverse proxy for grafana?

Tags: grafana, reverse-proxy, traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-middleware

I try to use traefik as a reverse proxy for grafana. I want to route the requests coming to localhost/grafana to grafana. Here is my that part of docker compose file:

```
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:9.4.2
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    environment:
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=localhost
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://localhost
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.rule=(Host(`localhost`) && Path(`/grafana`))"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.routegrafana.replacepath.path=/"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.middlewares=routegrafana"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Is there something i am missing?

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/

But still could not do it. It gives me an error saying: 404 page not found.

Comment: Try setting `traefik.enable` to `true`, specifying an `entrypoint` and also reading the logs.

Comment: to enable traefik for grfana endpoint you have to add this to labels
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.grafana.entrypoints=XXX"